# What is difference between below Code 1 & Code 2?

Tags: java

**Code 1**

```
String ccMailAddresses="abc@co.in,xyz@co.in";
String ccMailAddressArray[]=ccMailAddresses.split(",");
for (int index = 0; index < ccMailAddressArray.length; index++) {
    System.out.println(ccMailAddressArray[index]);
}
```

**Code 2**

```
String ccMailAddresses="abc@co.in,xy";
for (String ccMailAddress : ccMailAddresses.split(",")){
    System.out.println(ccMailAddress );
}
```

Which is best practice ? Is any performance hit in any one of them ?

Comment: one is for loop and other is foreach/enhancefor loop (used for traversing when there is no need of index )

Comment: Code 1 is nonsense because the `if` condition is always true. It is best practice not to write random tautological `if` statements.

Comment: There is not really a difference. `Code 1` makes an unnecessary check if the array is `null`. I think `split()` returns just an empty array but never `null`.

Comment: The `for` loops are identical except that in one you always know the current `index` whereas in the other one (the for-each loop)  you don't care about the index.

Comment: There is no big difference in computational cost for above two cases. [Enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) is normally used for iterate over collections as well as Array

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the second piece of code is **shorter** and working on a **higher level** of abstraction - as it is using a for-each loop; instead of that counting-for loop.

In that sense: code2 requires less efforts for the reader to grasp what is going on. So, from that perspective, it is definitely "better" than code1.

Performance wise, there shouldn't be any different between the two.

Answer (score 0):

The code does nearly the same thing. The if-statement in Code1 is useless. In my opinion this is alway true.

The difference is betweeen those two line:

```
for (int index = 0; index < ccMailAddressArray.length; index++)
```

Here your code will be executed until your index is bigger than the lenght of your array.

```
for (String ccMailAddress : ccMailAddresses.split(","))
```

The code in this loop is executed for every element in your array.

**But keep in mind the result is the same!**

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

No difference between both code:

code1 is traditional for loop , and code2 is for each loop introduced for java collection to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

**Code 1**

```
String ccMailAddresses="abc@co.in,xyz@co.in";
String ccMailAddressArray[]=ccMailAddresses.split(",");
if(ccMailAddressArray!=null){
    for (int index = 0; index < ccMailAddressArray.length; index++) {
        System.out.println(ccMailAddressArray[index]);
    }
}
```

In this example you make an unnecessary check against `ccMailAddressArray` because `split()` will never return `null`. The for loop here provides you an `index`. This can be useful sometimes e.g. if you have a `color` array that has a color stored for each element. Then you could use `color[index]` to select the color for each element and draw it somewhere. Please now, that this is a bit more complex than just iterating over all items. So you use this version whenever you *need* the `index`.

**Code 2**

```
String ccMailAddresses="abc@co.in,xy";
for (String ccMailAddress : ccMailAddresses.split(",")){
    System.out.println(ccMailAddress );
}
```

In this example you do essentially the same. The for-each loop you're using here does the same for you. The only difference is that you don't have the `index` here. It's just a bit shorter and simpler which makes it also easier to read.

So: Use for-each (Code 2) whenever you can because it is a bit simpler to understand what you are dong. If you use the index based for loop (Code 1) I assume you want to *do* something with `index` which also implies that some more complicated things may be involved.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for an answer stackoverflowgigs.**

My question is solved now!. As one of my senior gave me the review comment about code 2 is performance hit by repeatedly calling `ccMailAddresses.split(",")` in for each loop.